# How to retrieve staking credential hash

Tags: wallet, cardano-serialization-lib, hash

How to retrieve staking credential hash using cardano serialization library and what is it? How does it differ from public key hash?

Comment: Needs some more details.  Try searching for "staking credential" here and seeing how others have asked.

Comment: Try referring https://github.com/StricaHQ/typhonjs, it's a pure js library. It has many util functions which might be useful for you.

Comment: I Can't find much info about it. I think it is address stake credential converted into key hash.

Comment: You should add more details in your question, provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require an instance of type `BaseAddress` which you can get using a **bech32** formatted address (`addr_...` or `addr_test...`). Here an example:

```
const bech32Addr = "addr_test1qpgljxnfw696g0zslw0p6y4z5qt3vdlxws3e5d2ghftrvgtt0t2lsj2wyyal9d5s5ga3204hzkzrsah9ndu2d7zvqezsl7shc6";
const addr = BaseAddress.from_address(Address.from_bech32(bech32Addr));

console.log(addr.stake_cred().to_keyhash()); // Ed25519KeyHash | undefined
console.log(addr.stake_cred().to_scripthash()); // ScriptHash | undefined
```

In regards to how they differ from PubKeyHashes:
I recommend taking a look at the possible constructors for staking credentials which can be found here:
https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Credential.html#t:StakingCredential

Generally, if a staking credential was created using the `Credential` constructor which itself can be constructed using either `PubKeyCredentials` or `ScriptCredentials` you already see that staking credentials are not just pub key hashes. They could be validator hashes if a script manages staking actions for that address or even a staking pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I needed. :)

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can mark my response as answer :)

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!